# How to fix error " object of type 'NoneType' has no len() " when creating a web scraper?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm trying to create a web scraper to download certain images from a webpage using Python and BeautifulSoup. I'm a beginner and have built this just through finding code online and trying to adapt it. My problem is that when I run the code, it produces this error:

```
line 24, in <module> 
if len(nametemp) == 0:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
i = 1

def makesoup(url):
     thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
     soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
     return soupdata

soup = makesoup("https://www.stiga.pl/sklep/koszenie-trawnika/agregaty-tnace/agregaty-tnace-park-villa/agregat-park-100-combi-3-el-qf")
for img in soup.findAll('img'):
    temp=img.get('src')
    if temp[:1]=="/":
        image = "https://www.stiga.pl/sklep/koszenie-trawnika/agregaty-tnace/agregaty-tnace-park-villa/agregat-park-100-combi-3-el-qf" + temp
    else:
        image = temp

    nametemp = img.get('alt', [])
    if len(nametemp) == 0:
        filename = str(i)
        i = i + 1
    else: 
        filename = nametemp
```

This works now! Thanks for the replies!
Now when I run the code, only some of the images from the webpage appear in my folder. And it returns this:
    
    `Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "scrape_stiga.py", line 31, in <module>
    imagefile.write(urllib .request.urlopen(image).read())
    File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 
    222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 
    510, in open
    req = Request(fullurl, data)
    File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 
    328, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
    File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 
    354, in full_url
    self._parse()
    File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 
    383, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
    ValueError: unknown url type: 'assets/img/logo-white.png'`

Comment: You error message says that `nametemp` is `None`, and therefore has no `len`. If you expect that `img.get('alt')` will always return something - it doesn't, and it's a bug. But if you allow that outcome to be None, then you can change `if len(nametemp) == 0` to `if nametemp` to account for both None and a sequence with zero length.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the length of `nametemp` when the error is raised. It says you can't take the length of a `NoneType` object. This tells you that `nametemp` at that point must be `None`.

Why is it `None`? Let's go back to:

`nametemp = img.get('alt')`

OK. `img` is the current `<img>` tag, since you're iterating over image tags. At some point you iterate over an image tag which does not have an `alt` attribute. Therefore, `img.get('alt')` returns `None`, and `None` is assigned to `nametemp`.

Check the HTML you are parsing and confirm that all image tags have an `alt` attribute. If you only want to iterate over image tags with an `alt` attribute, you can use a css-selector to find only image tags with an `alt` attribute, or you could add a try-catch to your loop, and simply `continue` if you come across an image tag you don't like.

EDIT - You said you want to scrape product images, but it isn't really clear what page you are trying to scrape these images from exactly. You did update your post with a URL - thank you - but what exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to scrape the page that contains all (or some) of the products within a certain category, and simply scrape the thumbnails? Or do you want to visit each product page individually and download the higher resolution image?

Here's something I put together: It just looks at the first page of all products within a certain category, and then scrapes and downloads the thumbnails (low resolution) images into a `downloaded_images` folder. If the folder doesn't exist, it will create it automatically. This does require the third party module `requests`, which you can install using `pip install requests` - though you should be able to do something similar using `urllib.request` if you don't want to install `requests`:

```
def download_image(image_url):
    import requests
    from pathlib import Path

    dir_path = Path("downloaded_images/")
    dir_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    image_name = image_url[image_url.rfind("/")+1:]
    image_path = str(dir_path) + "/" + image_name


    with requests.get(image_url, stream=True) as response:
        response.raise_for_status()
        with open(image_path, "wb") as file:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
                file.write(chunk)
            file.flush()
    print(f"Finished downloading \"{image_url}\" to \"{image_path}\".\n")

def main():

    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    root_url = "https://www.stiga.pl/"

    url = f"{root_url}sklep/koszenie-trawnika/agregaty-tnace/agregaty-tnace-park-villa"

    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    for product in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "products__item"}):
        image_url = root_url + product.find("img")["data-src"]
        download_image(image_url)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

To recap, you are using BeautifulSoup to find the URLs to the images, and then you use a simple `requests.get` to download the image.

Comment: Cheers! It's fixed, but now there is a different response, and not all images are being downloaded from the website.

Comment: @jankomag It looks like at some point, as you're scraping URLs from the page, you come across a relative URL `assets/img/logo-white.png`, which you then pass to `makesoup`. You will have to reconstruct the absolute URL - but why are you trying to parse an image with BeautifulSoup in the first place? Maybe you can update your post and show more of your code?

Comment: I see. So basically I want to download product images from a website that I have now linked in the code. Again, I'm just starting with Python, so this may be a wrong approach to this problem, altogether. Would you have any advice on how to do this? Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try to make it work for me

Answer (score 0):

Replace `nametemp = img.get('alt')` with `nametemp = img.get('alt', '')`.

Some `<img>` elements could be missing the `alt` attribute. In such a case, `img.get('alt')` will return `None` and `len` function doesn't work on `None`.

By using `img.get('alt', '')`, you are returning an empty string when the image lacks `alt` attribute. `len('')` will return 0 and your code will not break.

Comment: Thank you! That's solved now. However now when I run the code, it produces a different response, which I edited into this post.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like nametemp is being assigned none ( that’s the default behaviour of get ).

In order to ensure nametemp is iterable, try changing your assignment line:

```
nametemp = img.get('alt',[])
```

This will ensure that if `“alt”` isn’t found that you will return a list and thus you can call `“len”`.

To control which directory your file is stored to, simply change your filename to contain the whole path i.e: “C:/Desktop/mySpecialFile.jpeg”

Comment: Thanks, now it seems that there is some other problem because not all images are being downloaded.